# Existence of a specific continuous linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be Hilbert spaces, and $\mathbb{L}$ be the collection of continuous linear operators from $B_1$ to $B_2$. Then, I wonder whether this statement is true: Given $x\in B_1,$ $y\in B_2,$ there always exists some $l \in \mathbb{L}$ such that $l(x)=y.$

Comment: Do you know Hahn Banach ?

Comment: I actually thought that the result should hold true as a consequence of some restatement of the Hahn Banach theorem, but cannot make clear the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1$ defined on $Vect(x)$ you can extend it to a continuous linear function $g$ on $B_1$ (Hahn Banach). Write $h(z)=g(z)y$, ut is bounded since $\|h(z)\|\leq |g(z)|\|y\|\leq \|g\|\|y\|\|z\|$.

Comment: I understood, thanks. To whom it might be confusing, let f: span({x}) → R be such that f(hx)=h, where x is any nonzero element in B1. Then, f is a continuous linear functional so that it may be extended to the entire space B1. Then, the remaining part is trivial.